# jquery Each function to add rows to a table

Tags: jquery

[image]I have two jquery functions. The first one adds rows and second one adds columns. I ran into this problem after creating my addColumns function. When I add Columns before I add rows the rows functions does not know that there are new tds added. Is there a way to create the same function I have for addColumns, but instead of hard coding the html for every td use an each function? That way my add rows function will know to check for new tds?

Or maybe there is any easier approach to this problem than the way I am going about it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var rowCount = $('#main tr').length;
        var tdCount = $("#main tr:first > td").length;
        console.log(tdCount);

        $('.addRow').click(function(){

            var markup = ("<tr>\
                            <td id='h-gi-"+rowCount+"-"+1+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-"+rowCount+"-"+2+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-"+rowCount+"-"+3+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-"+rowCount+"-"+4+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-gi-"+rowCount+"-"+5+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='i-"+rowCount+" class='h-text'>Enter Initiative"+" "+rowCount+" "+"here</td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+1+"-"+rowCount+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+2+"-"+rowCount+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+3+"-"+rowCount+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+4+"-"+rowCount+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                            <td id='h-it-"+5+"-"+rowCount+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
                        </tr>");

                $(markup).insertBefore($(".bottom-row"));
                $('tr:last').css("width", "75px");
                $('tr:last').prev().css("text-align", "center");
                rowCount++;
        });

        $('.addColumn').click(function() {
            $('#main').find('tr').each(function() {
                $(this).find('td').eq(tdCount -1).after("<td id='h-gi-"+rowCount+"-"+1+"' class='harvey'><img src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>");
            });
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Share your html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how you can add columns and rows and keep track of the column numbers and row numbers.

```js
$('#addColumn').on('click', function(){
  var $rows = $('#mytable').find('tr');
  
  $rows.each(function(index){
    var colCount = $(this).find('td').length + 1;
    
    var $newTd = $('<td>');
    $newTd.text(colCount + '-' + (index + 1));
    $(this).append($newTd);
  });
});

$('#addRow').on('click', function(){
  var rowCount = $('#mytable').find('tr').length + 1;
  var colCount = $('#mytable').find('tr').first().find('td').length;

  $('#mytable').append('<tr>');
  var $newRow = $('#mytable').find('tr').last();
  
  for(var i = 0 ; i < colCount; i++) {
    var $newTd = $('<td>');
    $newTd.text((i + 1) + '-' + rowCount);
    $newRow.append($newTd);
  }
});
```

```css
#mytable td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>1-1</td>
    <td>2-1</td> 
    <td>3-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1-2</td>
    <td>2-2</td> 
    <td>3-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="addColumn">Add Column</button>
<button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be not perfect but it may give you idea of what you want . just count the coulmns of the last row you added and then loop until the length of  in the last row .

```
 var cols = $("table").find("tr:last td"); 
$('.addColumn').click(function() {
   var markup = ("<tr>\
   for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++)
   {
     if(i == 4)
     { 
        "<td id='i-"+rowCount+" class='h-text'>Enter Initiative"+" "+rowCount+" 
        "+"here</td>\"
          return; }

        "<td id='h-gi-"+rowCount+"-"+1+"' class='harvey'><img 
        src='../Images/HarveyBalls/harvey-null.svg'/></td>\
   }
</tr>");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems be correct. Just a typo error near the line

```
<td id='i-"+rowCount+" class='h-text'>Enter Initiative"+" "+rowCount+" "+"here</td>\
```

Change it to

```
<td id='i-"+rowCount+"' class='h-text'>Enter Initiative"+" "+rowCount+" "+"here</td>\
```

you are missing single quote after `rowCount+"`